# Installing app on Android made in eclipse, not showing up in app drawer

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I  install it through dropbox, rather than running through my phone or the emulator, it debugs fine, it installs fine (it took me a bit to get it installing, but it installs, but gives me no option to open)

I signed it and everything to get it to install. I'm running it on a Samsung Galaxy Mega with Android 4.2.2.

This is what I have so far. It's very basic. I just want to get it running on my phone so I can go further in testing as I go on. Any suggestions welcome, and I am very new with Android stuff, so please don't laugh too hard!

Android Manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

activity main

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/vdep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:text="Very Depressed" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/moddep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vdep"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vdep"
        android:text="Moderately Depressed" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/milddep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/moddep"
        android:layout_below="@+id/moddep"
        android:text="Mildly Depressed" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/stable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/milddep"
        android:layout_below="@+id/milddep"
        android:text="Stable" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stable"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stable"
        android:text="Mildly Manic" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:text="Moderately Manic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vdep"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="View Charts" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:text="Very Manic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any and all suggestions are welcome. I'm running this on Windows 8, but I also have it installed on Linux, Ubuntu, if that would make life easier for me, let me know. Thanks a LOT guys. I always get answers here, and they're always good ones. (That's why I come!) Ask me any questions if needed and I'll try to answer quickly.

For the tl,dr, I have the code above, I can install on my phone, but it won't open, and the icon doesn't show in the Apps section of my phone, but it shows in Applications manager. My phone is in Debug mode.

Comment: You have no intent filter for a launcher activity in your Manifest.  Please see any Android example project.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go look around at it, and code it up, and let you know. That'll do it, won't it. Pardon my ignorance, this is my first attempt. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't guess. Visit developer.android.com.  It has everything you need.

Comment: Thank you Simon, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You also don't have any activity in your manifest. Did you copied the layout.XML from somewhere? Try to add itbmanually to your project and then copy the content.

Comment: Thanks. I did it myself, it just wasn't there in my manifest. I'm doing it on my Linux netbook now, which has a launcher included.. seem to be missing a lot on my Windows copy. Thanks. Having more success.

Comment: I copied this off of Linux, since I was having no luck on that either... one sec, let me figure this out...